# Round decimals row-wise instead of column-wise in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rounding

According to the `pandas.DataFrame.round` documentation I can decide the rounding also column-wise. However, there is nothing written about a row-wise rounding.
For instance, I have

```
               A
count       1010.00009
measure     54.45678
average     0.50483
```

How could I make it that

```
               A
count       1010
measure     54.46
average     0.5048
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When something supports columns but not the index, your only option is to transpose... twice.

```
df.T.round(decimals=dict(zip(df.index, [0, 2, 4]))).T
```

Or,

```
df.T.round(decimals=pd.Series([0, 2, 4], index=df.index)).T
```

Adding a `.astype(object)` call at the end, we have—

```
              A
count      1010
measure   54.46
average  0.5048
```

Comment: thanks you, @COLDSPEED: Although specifying `0, 2, 4` your solution seem to display all numbers with 4 digits.

Comment: You could just add the `astype(object)` from Wen's solution to remove those.

Comment: @eternity1 See chrisz's comment above. But I don't recommend doing so unless this is just for display purposes.

Comment: thank you very much. I didn't know what `astype(object)` in fact was doing. Actually I want that dataframe exported a csv or excel file and from there to a LaTex file, which is why I am looking to get the "final output" ready from here already.

Answer (score 4):

With `zip` and `round`(from python), and for print I am adding `astype(object)`

```
df.A=[round(x,y) for x , y in zip(df.A,[0,2,4])]
df.astype(object)

              A
count      1010
measure   54.46
average  0.5048
```

Comment: Thank you, @Wen: Would that also work when I have multiple columns? or do I have to transpose twice as COLDSPEED suggest? or would need to do it for each of the columns in case of multiple column?

Comment: @eternity1 In case of multiple columns, you need to do this for each column. This is better for a single series. For a DataFrame, I would recommend double transposition (my answer).

Answer (score 0):

We transpose DataFrame and we round the columns and Transpose again.

```
df = df.T.round( { "row_name": 0, "row2" : 2, "row3" : 4 } ).T
```